# Why the timer can't work when use libary of asio?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

the codes is:

Initialize the object：

```
tcp_client tcp_client_obj(*this,io_service,tcp_peer_context, ip_, port_, "", datas, ret, stdout_msgs, stderr_msgs,peer_check_flag_,deploy_type_);
            io_service.run();
```

the member functions:

```
  void tcp_client::handle_total_timeout(const boost::system::error_code& error_)
       {
            if (error_ != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
            {
                stderr_msgs.push_back("proxy total timeout");
                ret = MESSAGE_ERROR_CLIENT_TOTAL_TIMEOUT;
                close();
            }
        }

    void tcp_client::start()
        {
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(socket.get_io_service());
            string temp = boost::lexical_cast<string>(port);
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(ip.c_str(), temp.c_str());
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);


            total_timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(total_timeout));
            total_timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&tcp_client::handle_total_timeout,  this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

            connect_timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(connect_timeout));
            connect_timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&tcp_client::handle_connect_timeout,  this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

            now_time = global::currenttime::getms();
            boost::asio::async_connect(socket.lowest_layer(), iterator, boost::bind(&tcp_client::handle_connect, this,boost::asio::placeholders::error));
            LDeployInfo(str(format("[TCP Client] Connecting server@%s:%d") % ip % port));
        }
```

And I want to test the function of handle_total_time(). So I add the codes

```
bool tcp_client::check_release_md5()
    {
          while()
          {
             //just test this.
          }
          /*
           * do somethings.
           */
         }
```

the check_release_md5 will be called after the function of start(). 
**Why the handle_total_timeout() can't work**? 
Actually,the check_release_md5 will run forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit:
Dear people from the future:
As it turned out, the problem was that the first handler that was called, never returned. As such io_service was unable to post() the second one, which would have cancelled the first.

First let me state my personal opinion: Mark member variables in some way.

Do you guarantee that io_service.run() it is still running when you get here? To be more precise, do you maybe call io_service.run() after constructing but before calling start()?

In that case io_service has returned already and nothing will be handled. And another possibility: Did io_service maybe run() at some earlier point in your code and you forgot to reset() it?

Comment: thank you.  "io_service.run();" after the function of start(); the start() will be called in "tcp_client tcp_client_obj()";the order is:"tcp_client tcp_client_obj()", "start()", " io_service.run()".

Comment: I might be stupid here, but then where and when do you call check_release_md5()? Basically: Does io_service.run() return at all?

Comment: Because if it returns and run() has been called after the async_wait() of any of its deadline_timers, it should either have thrown an exception or posted the handler... Maybe, just maybe, your deadline_timer left scope at some point? In that case the handler would have been called with operation_aborted...

Comment: the order is:"tcp_client tcp_client_obj()"=> "start()"=>"check_release_md5()"=>" io_service.run()".Actually, I bulid a tcp_client and check the md5 with server. So "check_release_md5()" is after "start()" and before "io_server.run()".

Comment: And what do you mean by "Actually,the check_release_md5 will run forever."? Sorry, i seem to not understand what which component is doing at what time. ^^ The program does actually get to the line with io_service.run() right? And does the thread that happens in get past that line? While the tcp_client object still exists? Or more specifically: While the deadline_timer still exists?

Comment: ""Actually,the check_release_md5 will run forever."" means "while(true){}" is always running, not stop. you see. the " handle_total_timeout() " should stop it when the time is out.

Comment: And the "io_service.run()" is called after initialize the object of tcp_client.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41259/discussion-between-devadder-and-lxgeek)

Comment: How to verification "the deadline_timer still exists"?